# Hibernate missing column error in @OneToMany and @ManyToOne bidirectional association

Tags: java, hibernate

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Jugadores` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci' NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `apellidos` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci' NOT NULL COMMENT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  COMMENT ''
)


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Acciones` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `accion` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `idJugador` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_acciones_jugadores_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idJugador`)
    REFERENCES `Jugadores` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```

)

And here are my Java Classes:

Jugador:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="Jugadores")    
public class Jugador{

        private int id;
        private String nombre;
        private String apellidos;

        private Map<Integer, Accion> accionesJugador;


        public Jugador() {}

        /**
         * @return the id
         */
        @Override
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        /**
         * @param id the id to set
         */
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        /**
         * @return the nombre
         */
        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        /**
         * @param nombre the nombre to set
         */
        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

        /**
         * @return the apellidos
         */
        public String getApellidos() {
            return apellidos;
        }

        /**
         * @param apellidos the apellidos to set
         */
        public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
            this.apellidos = apellidos;
        }

        /**
         * @return the accionesJugador
         */
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "jugador")
        @MapKey
        public Map<Integer, Accion> getAccionesJugador() {
            return accionesJugador;
        }

        /**
         * @param accionesJugador the accionesJugador to set
         */
        public void setAccionesJugador(Map<Integer, Accion> accionesJugador) {
            this.accionesJugador = accionesJugador;
        }

    }
```

Accion:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "Acciones")
public class Accion {

    private int id;
    private int accion; 
    private Jugador jugador;
    public Accion(){};

    @Override
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the accion
     */
    public int getAccion() {
        return accion;
    }

    /**
     * @param accion the accion to set
     */
    public void setAccion(int accion) {
        this.accion = accion;
    }

    /**
     * @return the jugador
     */
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "idJugador")
    public Jugador getJugador() {
        return jugador;
    }

    /**
     * @param jugador the jugador to set
     */
    public void setJugador(Jugador jugador) {
        this.jugador = jugador;
    }
```

And the Hibernate log says:

> Initial SessionFactory creation
>   failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column:
>   accionesJugador_KEY in HBAssistant.Acciones

**EDIT:** The key in the `Map<Integer, Accion> accionesJugador` is the id of the 
`Accion`

**SOLVED:** The code above resolves my original problem

Comment: Sounds like a foreign key issue. Are there any conventions / constraints about foreign key names? (I don't know hibernate)

Comment: You want a Map<Integer, Accion> in Jugador. But you haven't told Hibernate what the key of the map should be. It's an Integer, but coming from where?

Comment: I've updated my question. The key of the map is the ID of Accion (the data that is the value of each entry in the map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using a map in your @OneToMany relationship.

you need to give JPA the key :

```
@MapKey
```

if the key id not the primary key field

```
@MapKey(name = "something")
```

in your code :

```
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "jugador")
        @MapKey
        public Map<Integer, Accion> getAccionesJugador() {
            return accionesJugador;
        }
```

Comment: I did what you suggested and i got another error:     Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: acciones_KEY in HBAssistant.Acciones

Comment: where is te declaration of the field "id" in your class Accion ? you just missed something in your copy/paste here or ?

Comment: I've updated my question. Sorry i did wrong the copy/paste.

Comment: next thing is : your getId method in Accion class is not "visible", did you forget the "public" key word ?

Comment: Yes, I forgot it. Added and getting the same error.

Comment: Solved. I had a mistake because of my classes had more bidirectional relationships. But i wanted to smplify them here for foucusing better in the problem. Thanks @Pras.